# Best way of rendering a nested list of objects in a Sammy.js template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sammy.js

I'm brand new to Sammy.js and am struggling with template rendering...

What's the best way of rendering a template in a Sammy.js app when your data contains a combination of single key-value pairs, but also a list?

Example data:

```
{'report-name': 'Some Report',
'people': [{'name': 'Bob'}, {'name': 'Sally'}, {'name': 'John'}]}
```

From looking at the API, there is `.render()` and `.renderEach()`,but I don't see anything that specifically addresses my example.

On a side note, I know `.render()` doesn't add the result of render to the DOM automatically, so in my case, I would need to append the result of the rendering to two different DOM elements. Can I simply assign the output of `.render()` to a variable?

If I need to call `.render()` twice, once for the `report_name` and once for the `people` values, that's fine, I just need to know what the best practice is.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Do you have 2 different templates that you need to render? One taking the KV pairs and the other one the list?

Comment: Not currently, but I could certainly break it up that way. I would just need to be able to combine all of the output at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the Sammy Template plugin: https://github.com/quirkey/sammy/blob/master/lib/plugins/sammy.template.js

Which is based on jQuery Templates. This allowed me to access the list of objects by key, then iterate over them.